# Are C++ bools converted to ints during comparison?

Tags: c++

When using comparison operators in C++, are bools converted to ints?

The reason I ask is that the question of whether or not to always explicitly compare to true/false in if-statements came up. The two options being:

```
1) if (my_bool == true) doSomething();
2) if (my_bool) doSomething();
```

We were thinking you should generally avoid the explicit comparison (1) because of the following:

```
int myFunc(){return 4;}
if (myFunc() == true) doSomething();
```

Something like the code above would come up if you need to work with C interfaces that simply return nonzero to indicate "true". The `myFunc()` example would fail in C because `myFunc` returns 4, `true` is macro'd to 1, and `4 == 1` is not true.

Is this still the case in C++? Does the "equal to" operator convert the bool to an int rather than the other way around? References to the standard (C++11 is what I'm working with) are appreciated, but if it differs among versions of the language I'd be interested in knowing.

(I'd like to ask specifically about the pros/cons of explicit true/false comparison, but that seems like it could be subjective.)

Comment: Assume that `if (myBool == true)` is better than `if (myBool)`, then obviously `if ((myBool == true) == true)` is even better !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When using comparison operators in C++, are bools converted to ints?

**Yes.** For relational operators ([expr.rel]/5):

> The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on operands of arithmetic or enumeration type.

For equality operators ([expr.eq]/6):

> If both operands are of arithmetic or enumeration type, the usual arithmetic conversions are performed on
>   both operands;

When both operands are `bool`, they are both promoted to `int`. If one operand is a `bool` and the other is of integral type, the `bool` operand is promoted to `int`. See [expr]/10:

> Otherwise, the integral promotions (4.5) shall be performed on both operands.

As far as I know, this has been true since the beginning of time (it does not differ between revisions of the standard).

I do not think there is any performance implication of doing explicit comparison to `true` or `false`, but I wouldn't do it myself, since I consider it redundant and not in a way that yields any benefit.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not concerned about performance so much as I am by safety and potential pitfalls of each approach.

Comment: Perormance is a non-issue. Compilers understand booleans well enough to optimize any reasonable variation.

Answer (score 1):

They are not converted, bool actually ARE integer types.

See the standard:

"Values of type bool are either true or false. As described below, bool values behave as integral types. Values of type bool participate in integral promotions" ~ C++03